# ms SQL update column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question is, how do you update a field value in a MS Query by 1 ? I am trying to add 1 (+1) to an column in my SQL Server, and I only want the update to alter values between 200 to 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a basic `UPDATE`. Use the `SET` clause to modify columns. Use `WHERE` clause to decide which rows to update:

```
update tablename
    set col = col + 1
where col >= 200 and col <= 500
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query.

```
UPDATE <YOUR_TABLE_NAME>
   SET <COLUMN_NAME> = <COLUMN_NAME> + 1
WHERE <COLUMN_NAME> BETWEEN 200 and 500
```

Hope i answered your question

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful